# How do I make linked references to sections of the same document using Markdown where the heading title is a sentence with spaces?

Tags: markdown, documentation, github-flavored-markdown, multimarkdown

While this works

```
1. [Notifier system requirements](#requirements)
```

This does not work

```
1. [Deployment steps](#steps to deployment)
```

`Steps to deployment` and `requirements` are the header/section titles in my `README.md` file.

Comment: "steps" or "Steps" ?

Comment: @albert neither "steps" nor "Steps" works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the target of the rendered header, either by mousing over it or by inspecting it with your browser's devtools. You should find that the target for your "Steps to deployment" header isn't `steps to deployment`, but rather `steps-to-deployment`.

Update your link like so and it should work:

```
1. [Deployment steps](#steps-to-deployment)
```

Answer (score 7):

According to this [filter](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/toc_filter.rb) (linked from [github/markup](https://github.com/github/markup)), GitHub uses the following steps to convert text to a slug:

1. Convert all characters to lowercase ASCII characters.
2. Remove all punctuation except spaces and hyphens.
3. Convert all spaces to hyphens.

Therefore, your link should be:

```
[Deployment steps](#steps-to-deployment)
```